# Writing DHTML with XSLT

Tags: javascript, xslt, dhtml

HTML is being written by XSLT.

- As an amateur XSLT developer
- I want to write a javascript block into the HTML (head or body)
- So that the script can be executed when the HTML is rendered (loo and behold, DHTML).

I know how to use script in the XSLT itself, but not how XSLT can write a script block to DHTML.
I know how to write the HTML by hand, but of course I want the XSLT to do the heavy-lifting.

The below code is what I expected to work, but doesn't. It simply displays the code in the head of the page.

```
<head>
    <title>My HTML</title>
    <msxsl:script type="text/javascript" version="1.3">
        <![CDATA[
            var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
            var i;

            for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
                coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var content = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (content.style.display === "block") {
                    content.style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                    content.style.display = "block";
                    }
                });
            }
        ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
</head>
```

[Script is displayed as text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNdrs.png)

This is for NHS work, so pretty please ... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML your XSLT creates is supposed to contain a HTML `script` element then you would literally insert it the same way as you have used a `head` or `title` element. In the XSLT, XSLT being XML, you would need to ensure your inline Javascript code doesn't break XML rules, as you have done with the CDATA section, but the `script` element would be a plain `script` element and not an `msxsl:script` element.

Other than that and using `xsl:output method="html"`, there is not anything special.

It is questionable what your particular code in the `head` section using `var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");` and trying to process that collection is supposed to achieve before any elements are parsed but that is rather a question of the appropriate use of Javascript and perhaps an event handler or a function call instead of inline code.

Depending on where your XSLT is executed (client or server), the whole interaction of XSLT and Javascript can be brittle, adding script dynamically, even without XSLT, can be a challenge cross-browser.

Comment: This is a dark art! Thanks @Martin Honnen, since removing the "msxml" part worked.

Comment: ... worked to allow the script to be written into the HTML appropriately.
Whereas now you're insight into document.getElementsByClassName is likely hitting me now. When I render the HTML, there are script errors. I think I understand your guidance here too - but please may I check? Are you saying make it an event handler and not inline? That chimes, because the idea is for it to be called when a collapsible section is collapsed or expanded.

Comment: In any case, whether with Javascript inside static HTML or inside the HTML generated by XSLT, I would think that you want to run your code inside of a DOMContentLoaded event listener e.g. `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible"); ... }, false);` so that it is run when there is a complete DOM to access all the elements you want to process. Some people might prefer not to use the DOMContentEvent listener but to place the script element you have at the very end of the body but I think using the event listener is cleaner.

Comment: Thank you Martin - makes good sense and I agree it is cleaner

Comment: Can you raise that problem in a new, separate question where you tell us all the necessary details like browser, browser version, document mode for IE or Edge and then add minimal but complete snippets as code snippets? It is a bit hard to read code inserted in comments. In general, when writing Javascript to be used in HTML generated by XSLT, I would first try to develop and test the code in static HTML, if that works, it should also work in XSLT generated HTML, unless you end up using `document.write` or similar that is not supported in Mozilla.